# can not access iis hosted wcf from remote machine

Tags: wcf, iis

I have hosted a wcf on IIS when I write its url to the same machine's browser it works but when I try to access it from a remote machine or mobile on the same LAN I get this message :
  500 - Internal server error

how can I solve this problem?!

any ideas!

Comment: You have hosted a wcf? A wcf what? A wcf banana? A wcf giraffe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to determine the root cause may be to enable WCF Tracing on both the client application and host service. Oftentimes, the WCF Trace log will reveal issues that were previously “hidden”.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx